# How to pass an array with unknown 1-d dimension into function in C

Tags: arrays, c

I try something like below but all the time I have a segmentation fault.
I don't really want to use (e.g.) `#define N 1000` and then declare `int buffer[N]`.

Just in case..I'm not allowed to use any headers except `stdio.h` as well as dynamic memory.

```
void input (int *buffer, int *length);

int main()
{
    int length, *buffer = NULL, *numbers = NULL;
    input(buffer, &length);
}

void input(int *buffer, int *length) {
    scanf("%d", length);
    if (*length < 0) {
        error = 1;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < *length; i++) {
        scanf("%d", *buffer[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: `buffer` is NULL. You need to either allocate memory first or pass in a pointer to that pointer and have the function do the allocation. Since the length input is inside the function the latter is probably most appropriate. If you are not allowed to use dynamic memory then you need to have a fixed size array.

Comment: You also have a problem with `scanf("%d", *buffer[i])`. If you want to read into an array of integers, then `*buffer[i]` should be `buffer+i`.

Comment: Arzental, Enable all warnings to rapidly find troubles like `scanf("%d", *buffer[i]);`.

Answer (score 2):

> How to pass an array with unknown 1-d dimension into function

In C, arrays cannot exist until their size is known.
There are other approaches though.

---

In C, code cannot pass an *array* to a function.  `some_function(some_array)` converts the array `some_array` to the address of the first element of the array: `&some_array[0]`.  That is what the function receives, a pointer, not an array.  The original size information of the array is not passed, thus also pass the length to the function.

---

Sample:

Read desired length.

```
{
  int length = 0;
  scanf("%d", &length);
```

Form a *variable length array*, `length >= 1`.

```
  if (length <= 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  int buffer[length];
```

Now call a function, passing the length and the address of the first element of the array.

```
  // Do stuff with length and buf, like read data
  foo1(length, buffer);
  // foo1() receives the length & address of the first element of the array as an int *
  // Do more stuff with length and buf, like write data
  foo2(length, buffer);
}
```

At the end of the block `}`, `buffer` no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can't create an array if you can't know its size at compile time (or at least not in certain implementations and standards), so doing something like `buffer[length]` won't work (again at least not in certain implementations/standards).

What you need to do to make sure this works everywhere is to use a pointer (as I see you're trying to use here). However, what you're doing wrong here that causes your segfault with the pointers is you assign them the value of NULL. This also won't work due to how when you assign a pointer an arbitrary value, there is no memory allocated for the pointer (This applies for everything other than addresses of "regular" variables using the `&` operator and assigning other pointers that are checked to be OK). Your pointers are just pointing to address 0 and can't be used for anything.

What you need to do here to fix the pointers is to use dynamic memory allocation, so you can have a truly variable-sized array. Specifically, you need to use a function like `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate memory for the pointers so they are usable. In your case, using `calloc` and reading [its documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/), we see that it takes 2 parameters: The number of elements it should allocate memory for and the size of each element. We also know that it returns a pointer to the starting address of the allocated memory and that in case of failure (which can only happen if you're out of memory), it returns NULL. Using this, we understand that in your case the call to `calloc` would be like this:

```c
int *buffer = (int *) calloc(length, sizeof(int));
```

The `sizeof()` function returns the size of a data type in bytes. Here you allocated enough memory for the pointer to hold `length` integers (since you'll use it as an array you need enough memory for all the integers, you're not just pointing to 1 integer but storing all of them), and `calloc` is also noted to initialize every allocated element to 0, so you have an array of integers that are all initialized to 0 (Also note that type casting has been used to make sure the allocated memory block is appropriate for use with an integer array, you can read more about type casting [in this small article from Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm) if you'd like). Then, after this has been allocated, you can start reading your integers into the array. The complete code looks like this:

```c
void input (int *buffer, int *length);

int main() {
    // NOTE: I don't see the numbers pointer used here, maybe remove it?
    int length, *buffer, *numbers;
    input(buffer, &length);
}

void input(int *buffer, int *length) {
    scanf("%d", length);
    if (*length < 0) {
        // Consider printing the exact error here
        error = 1;
        return;
    }
    
    buffer = (int *) calloc(length, sizeof(int));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
       printf("Couldn't allocate memory for buffer\n");
       error = 1;
       return;
    }

   
    // Accessing the elements of an array doesn't need * and in fact * here can (and probably will) cause terrible things
    for (int i = 0; i < *length; i++) {
        scanf("%d", buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to call `free()` on the pointer after you're done using it to avoid memory leaks (in your case that'd be after the call to `input()`).

Hope this helped, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use arrays because their memory size must be known to the compiler at compile time. Also you can't use [Variable Length Arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) because they are allocated at the point of declaration and deallocated when the block scope containing the declaration exits.
The solution to your problem might be to use [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc)